# awk; getting multiple lines from two files when they share a common header

Tags: awk, fastq

I have a question that is quite similar to many other questions regarding this topic, yet I am unable to extent these solutions to the exact output I am looking for.

I have two files that are formatted in fastq style, which looks like this:

file1.txt

```
@header:with:id:number:0001 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
ABCD
+
1324
@header:with:id:number:0001 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
EFGH
+
5678
@header:with:id:number:0002 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
PQRS
+
9012
@header:with:id:number:0003 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
IJKL
+
3456
@header:with:id:number:0003 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
MNOP
+
7890
```

file2.txt

```
@header:with:id:number:0004 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
QRST
+
1324
@header:with:id:number:0004 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
UVWX
+
5678
@header:with:id:number:0005 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
CDEF
+
3456
@header:with:id:number:0005 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
GHIJ
+
7890
@header:with:id:number:0002 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
YZAB
+
9012
```

Every 'block' has four lines from which the first (the header) always starts with @ and include an id-number (e.g. 0001) and an index (i.e. 1 or 2 after a 'space').
Every id-number should occur twice in the same file with both indices (like this is true for all id-numbers except 0002 in the above example).
Now I want to separately store the blocks whose id-number occurs in both files (indicating the blocks that occur only once in either file).

In this case the output should be:

```
@header:with:id:number:0002 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
PQRS
+
9012
@header:with:id:number:0002 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
YZAB
+
9012
```

and these lines should be removed from the original files.

For this I have so far used awk with the following command

```
awk -F" " '/^@/ && NR==FNR {lines[$1]; next}
    $1 in lines {x=NR+3}
    (NR<=x) {print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This outputs:

```
@header:with:id:number:0002 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
PQRS
+
9012
```

which half way there.

My question is, how do I search for id-numbers in the headers that occur in *both* files, store them in a third file and remove the corresponding blocks from both original files?

Comment: Is this [tag:fastq] format? You are more likely to reach people who work with this format if you identify it explicitly.

Comment: It sounds like really want to print and remove the blocks whose ID only occurs once in a file - that'd be a simpler task than comparing the IDs across both files to find which ID occurs in both files if that's going to always be the same IDs which only appear once in one file.

Comment: @EdMorton Ideally an id-number occurs twice in the same file, once with index 1 and once with index 2. But if one of the indices is missing it is expected that it occurs in the other file and thus that id-numbers occurs in both files. (This is due to some uncertainties in the downstream processing steps and these blocks should be treated differently and therefore I want to separate them). Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, this is indeed fastq format. Thanks for the tip, I'll update the question to mention this explicitly.

Comment: @MostlyHarmless yes, that's what you described in your question. My point is that  finding an ID that occurs once in a file and removing the associated record from that file is easier than finding an ID that occurs in both files and then removing the records from each files, so why not make THAT your requirement instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             RS="@header" # Set the input record separator
           } 
   FNR==NR { # process the first file
             ORS="@header"; # Set the output record separator
             split($0,map,":"); # Split the record into array map using ":" as the delimiter
             map1[substr(map[5],1,4)]=$0 # map[5] will be e.g 0002 2. We only want 0002 and so use substr to create an index for array map1 with the record as the value
           } 
   NR!=FNR { # process the second file
             ORS="@header";
             split($0,map,":");
             id=substr(map[5],1,4); # id e.g. 0002
             if (id in map1) { 
                               print $0; # If id in map1 array print this record
                               print map1[id] # if id in map1 array print array value
             } 
            }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

One liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="@header" } FNR==NR { ORS="@header";split($0,map,":");map1[substr(map[5],1,4)]=$0 } NR!=FNR { ORS="@header";split($0,map,":");id=substr(map[5],1,4);if (id in map1) { print $0;print map1[id] } }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tested this and it gives me the expected answer. Do I understand correctly that ```map[5],1,4``` gets the 5th element after separating by ':' and then ```1,4``` gets the first 4 digits of that 5th element? In that case, how can I extent this to instead looking for 4 digits look for an arbitrary number of digits?

Comment: Yeah substr 1,4 takes the 1st to the 4th character

Comment: you can probably use match(map[5],/^[[:digit:]]+/);substr(map[5],RSTART,RLENGTH)

Comment: That works indeed, although I had to remove the ';' before the ```substr``` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `gnu awk` to print all those headers that appears only once per file:

```sh
awk -v ORS= -v RS='@header:' -F '[:[:blank:]]+' 'NF {
   if ($4 in seen)
      delete seen[$4]
   else
      seen[$4] = prt $0
}
ENDFILE {
   for (i in seen)
      print seen[i]
   delete seen
}
{prt = RT}' file1 file2


@header:with:id:number:0002 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
PQRS
+
9012
@header:with:id:number:0002 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
YZAB
+
9012
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works nicely, but as far as I understand it does not explicitly look for whether a header occurs in both files, but rather gets all headers that do not have a pair in the same file. This is what I am looking for, I'm sorry if this was not clear from my question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples, should work in any `awk` I believe but could test it in GNU `awk` only.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^@/){
    match($0,/^@header:with:id:number:[0-9]{4}/)
    mat1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    arr1[mat1]++
  }
    val1[mat1]=(val1[mat1]?val1[mat1] ORS:"")$0
    next
}
{
  if($0~/^@/){
    match($0,/^@header:with:id:number:[0-9]{4}/)
    mat2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    arr2[mat2]++
  }
  val2[mat2]=(val2[mat2]?val2[mat2] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(key1 in arr1){
    if(arr1[key1]==1 && arr2[key1]==1){print val1[key1] ORS val2[key1] }
  }
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

This will look for count of matched indexes as `1` in both of the files mandatory in case you want have `1` count in either of the file then change `arr1[key1]==1 && arr2[key1]==1` to `arr1[key2]==1` in above condition.

Output will be as follows with shown samples.

```
@header:with:id:number:0002 2:this:number:indicates:pair:number
PQRS
+
9012
@header:with:id:number:0002 1:this:number:indicates:pair:number
YZAB
+
9012
```